# Calculate total time spent by group and one datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a workflow application where the workflow is written to the DB as shown below when the status changes. There is no end time as it is a sequence of events. I want to create a query that will group by the WorkFlowID and total the amount of time spent in each. I am not sure how to even begin

My table and data looks like this

```
+------------+---------------------+
| WorkFlowID |      EventTime      |
+------------+---------------------+
|          1 | 07/15/2015 12:00 AM |
|          2 | 07/15/2015 12:10 AM |
|          3 | 07/15/2015 12:20 AM |
|          2 | 07/15/2015 12:30 AM |
|          3 | 07/15/2015 12:40 AM |
|          4 | 07/15/2015 12:50 AM |
+------------+---------------------+
```

My end result should be like:

```
+------------+-----------------+
| WorkFlowID | TotalTimeInMins |
+------------+-----------------+
|          1 |              10 |
|          2 |              20 |
|          3 |              20 |
|          4 |              10 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you explain the calculation that generates the requested output values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would just use `lead()`.  There are several ways to approach this in SQL Server 2008.  Here is one using `outer apply:

```
select t.WorkFlowId,
       sum(datediff(second, EventTime, nextTime)) / 60.0 as NumMinutes
from (select t.*, t2.EventTime as nextTime
      from table t outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from table t2
            where t2.EventTime > t.EventTime
            order by t2.EventTime
           ) t2
     ) tt
group by t.WorkFlowId;
```

The only question is how you get "10" for event 4.  There is no following event, so that value doesn't make sense.  You can use `datediff(second, EventTime coalesce(NextEvent, getdate())` to handle the `NULL` value.

Comment: Yes you caught my oversight with event 4 and your solution for that also is pretty much what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventTime) As rn
    FROM
        yourTable)
SELECT
    t1.WorkFlowID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1.EventTime, ISNULL(t2.EventTime, GETDATE()) / 60)  As TotalTimeInMins
FROM t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2 
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The basis of a method that works in all (ok, I don't know about SQL 6.5) editions is to use the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT
   WorkFlowID
  ,datediff(mi, min(EventTime), max(EventTime))  TotalTimeInMins
 from MyTable
 group by WorkFlowID
```

This does indeed leave the question of how you got 10 minutes with a start time and (presumably) no end time. As written, this query would list the
WorkFlowID with TotalTimeInMins = 0, which seems accurate enough.  The following variant would remove all "start-only" items:

```
SELECT
   WorkFlowID
  ,datediff(mi, min(EventTime), max(EventTime))  TotalTimeInMins
 from MyTable
 group by WorkFlowID
 having count(*) > 1
```

(The quick explanation: `having` is to `group by` as `where` is to `from`)

Comment: ...unless I'm missing something, the problem *as described* does not require uber-complex windowing functions...

Comment: @PhillipKelley . . . You might look again at the desired results.  Your query would return "0" for `WorkflowID = 1`.  However, the OP wants 10.